# Highcharts - shared tooltips for certain serieses

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'd like to have the following behavior using highcharts.
I need to have 2 kinds of tooltips:

1. the default shared tooltip
2. a custom tooltip

for the custom tooltip I can use a simple tooltip formatter.
the problem is with the shared tooltip.
Is that possible to share the default tooltip with some serieses, and have a custom one to another?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but you need to use formatter and prepare logic. See the very simple demo http://jsfiddle.net/7gmxzwdf/5/

```
        formatter:function(){
            var txt = '',
                x = this.x,
                series = this.point.series.chart.series;

            if(this.series.options.shared) {
                $.each(series,function(i,s){
                    if(s.options.shared) {
                        $.each(s.data,function(j, d){
                            if(d.x === x) {
                                txt += '<span style="color:'+s.color+';font-weight:bold;">'+s.name+'</span> value: ' + d.y + '<br/>';
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            } else {
                txt = 'not shared value: ' + this.y;
            }

            return txt;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no obvious way in the API, but you can get something similar to what you want by detecting which series the mouse went over:

```
 var series1Selected=0;
 ...
 series: [{
        events: {
            mouseOver: function () {
                series1Selected = 1;
            },
            mouseOut: function () {
                series1Selected = 0;
            }
        },
```

You can then change the appearance of your tooltip in the formatter depending on whether you are hovered over series 1 or not.

```
 tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            if (series1Selected == 1) {
                var s = '<b>Series 1</b>';
            } else {
                var s = '<b>Shared</b>';
                $.each(this.points, function () {
                    s += '<br/>' + this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + 'm';
                });

            }
            return s;
        },
        shared: true
    },
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rjbfmob6/

It's a bit glitchy, but may serve as a basis for a solution.